# Making an account

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm trying to make an account but the google account making choice isn't there. So I tried to make a Pokemon club account but it says the email u you used to make an account can't be created.

Please tell me what to do.

Comment: @Dragonrage I disagree with this being a dupe. It's asking for specific help with creating a PTC account, but they are running into a known bug present in the game.

Answer (score 0):

According to an unaffiliated PokemonGo Servers Twitter, [this is a known issue and is being addressed by Niantic](https://twitter.com/PoGoServer/status/755083903283650560) at this time. The best thing to do in this case is to try again at a different time, or try using a Google account instead.